# How to use the nodejs request module in nodejs file and how to trigger that function?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, request

How call a certain route it should make a get request or this should be triggerred

```
app.get('/', function (request, response, next) {
  request({
    url: url,
    json: true
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      console.log(body) // Print the json response
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make get request you can simply use

```
request('www.example.com', function(error, response, body) {
// your code goes here
}).
```

Here's the step by step procedure.

#### Step 1

First, you should install `request` module for that you have to write the below command in your terminal to the root of your project directory,

```
npm install request
```

If you have want to save this module as dependency you can pass `--save` option with the above command.

#### Step 2

Now go to the file where you want to do `request`. Now you need to require `request` module to this file. Add below line to require your request module.

```
const request = require('request');
```

#### Step 3

Now it's time to do request you just need to use the simple 2-3 line of code where you want to do request. Here's the simple example.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  let url = "https://www.google.com"
  request.get({
    url: url,
    json: true
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      console.log(body) // Print the json response
    }
  })
});
```

### NOTE

Here we are using `request` variable to make `HTTP request`, So make sure that you are not using the same name for your `callback function in app.get()`. There you can use `req, res and next` parameter like

`app.get('/', function(req, res, next){});`

#### extra

Using request module you can do any type of request like GET, POST, PUT, DELETE.

[Here's the link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to get more about request module

Comment: Thanks pavan but how to call this request function inside the nodeJS?